# Using Rijndael initvectors/salt in public applications

Tags: .net, encryption

When I use Rijndael (in this case RijndaelManaged from .NET in Mono) in a public app which asks the user only for a password, what would be the best way to make the initvector and the salt? I cannot (possibly) generate + store them (as the document generated by the app needs to be opened on other systems with only the password).

Is it an idea to generate them, somehow, from the password? Like sha the password and then generate the salt and the initvector?

Can anyone help me with a secure way of doing this?

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to use [`Rfc2898DeriveBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwx8t0yt.aspx), aka [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2),  to generate an IV and a key from the password.

Given the same inputs -- password, salt and iteration count -- PBKDF2 will generate the same sequence of bytes every time which you can then use for your IV and key.

Ideally you would use a different salt for each encrypted document and then store the salt somewhere alongside the doc, but it sounds like your constraints mean that you can't do this, in which case you'll need to use a constant salt. Not ideal, but shouldn't present too much of a problem in most situations.

```
public void DoSomething(string password)
{
    byte[] iv, key;

    // default iteration count is 1000 if you don't specify in the constructor
    using (var deriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, _salt))
    {
        iv = deriveBytes.GetBytes(16);     // get 16 bytes for the iv
        key = deriveBytes.GetBytes(16);    // get another 16 bytes for the key
    }

    // now use iv and key to setup RijndaelManaged to encrypt or decrypt
}

// shared, constant salt - make this as long and unguessable as you like
private static readonly byte[] _salt = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
```

Comment: Rather than a constant salt, you could store a per-user salt, pseudo-randomly generated, when each user creates an account.  Use the salt as input into the PBKDF for that user.  A constant salt across all users is a security weakness.

Comment: @rossum: I agree that a constant salt weakens the security and that ideally you'd want a per-user -- or even per-encryption -- salt. But the OP suggests in their question that storing anything would be difficult or impossible in their situation.

Comment: Whoops, I didn't pick that up.  One solution might be to use a fixed salt and the password to generate a variable salt, (perhaps with a reduced number of iterations) and use the variable salt to generate the IV and key.  Thanks for the correction.